# How to change every string element of an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I have a `ListView` with an arraylist with an unknown number of string elements. I want to change/modify every single one of these string items. The problem is that i dont know how many items there are since the user can change it.

I have a `translate` function that takes a string and returns a string. What i want to do is

```
arraylistelement1 = translate(arraylistelement1);
arraylistelement2 = translate(arraylistelement2);
...
```

and repopulate the `listview` arraylist with the new strings.

Whats a way to do this?

Comment: How do i do it without knowing the number of elements?

Comment: Something like `(for int i=0; i< mArrayList.size(); i++){...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the list and create a new list of translated options from the original then replace the contents of the original list with the new values.  If you do the replacing while iterating you'll get ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Comment: ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String string : strings){
temp.add(translate(string));
}
strings = temp;

Comment: @MuratKaya He just did!

Comment: yes didnt see it before. I couldnt get the code to work though. I put my arraylist instead of strings. Do I replace string with anything?

Answer (score 2):

Use ListIterator.set:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("s0", "s1", "s2"));

    ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();

    while (iter.hasNext())
       iter.set(translate(iter.next()));

    for (String element : list)
        System.out.println(element);
}

public static String translate(String element) {
    return element + " " + Math.random();
}
```